# Android ListFragment scroll issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing an application on Android 3.2/4.0.3 for both phones and tablets. I have been using the Fragments functionality and on the left fragment I have extended the ListFragment and successfully added my own custom view to each list row (layout defined in its own XML file). My issue arises occasionally when scrolling, for some reason the list goes crazy and rows overlap and bounce around within the list. Has anyone come across this behaviour before?

I have attached some examples below. I have searched around trying to find examples of this happening, but I can't find any. There doesn't seem to be a bug report raised for it either, so I don't know if it's due to the way I've written the code or this is a "feature" of Android.

Any help would be much appreciated.

List Fragment working correctly - https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG2yN.png

Crazy List Fragment behaviour - https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDbm9.png

Comment: It isn't feature of Android. Could you post adapter code and layout XML?

Comment: I've uploaded some code to pastebin that might explain things better. When I say feature I was more referring to it being an Android bug or not.

Relevant Code:
- http://pastebin.com/Vs9CiS9P
- http://pastebin.com/ca9UmwXv
- http://pastebin.com/yY6LQUdL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about this function:

```
  public View getView(int p_position,
      View p_convertView,
      ViewGroup p_parent)
  {
    if (p_convertView == null)
    {
      return m_views.get(p_position);
    }
    else
    {
      return p_convertView;
    }
  }
```

Why are you returning p_convertView if it's not null? Android is probably spazzing out and using original views rather than creating new ones? Try this...

```
  public View getView(int p_position,
      View p_convertView,
      ViewGroup p_parent)
  {
    return m_views.get(p_position);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to fix it.